# Cube entity collision on plane entity

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

How do i do a collision between a cube and a plane, i can do a sphere on a plane but i cant figure out cube on a plane, i know i must find the x,y,z of the cube and do a detection on the plane but i cant figure it out.

Here is my collision tester code.

```
public static bool sphereAndSphere(Sphere a, Sphere b, ref Contact contact)
    {
        // Get the vector from the centre of particle B to the centre of particle A
        Vector3 separationVector = b.Position - a.Position;
        float sumOfRadii = a.Radius + b.Radius;
        float distance = separationVector.Length();

        if (distance < sumOfRadii)
        {
            contact.contactPoint = a.Position + separationVector / 2f;
            separationVector.Normalize();
            contact.contactNormal = separationVector;
            contact.penetrationDepth = sumOfRadii - distance;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // This assumes that the Origin is in the centre of world 
    // and that the planes are the boundaries of the world and that all rigid-bodies are within the boundaries
    public static bool sphereAndPlane(Sphere a, PlaneEntity b, ref Contact contact)
    {
        // Depth of sphere into plane (if negative, no collision)
        float depth = Vector3.Dot(a.Position, b.DirectionFromOrigin) + a.Radius + b.OffsetFromOrigin;

        if (depth > 0)
        {
            contact.contactPoint = a.Position + (a.Radius - depth) * b.DirectionFromOrigin;
            contact.contactNormal = -b.DirectionFromOrigin;
            contact.penetrationDepth = depth;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here a test on cube on box

```
public static bool sphereAndBox(Sphere a, Cube b, ref Contact contact)
    {
        Vector3 relativePoint = Vector3.Transform(a.Position, Matrix.Invert(b.WorldTransform));

        // Early out check, based on separation axis theorem
        if (Math.Abs(relativePoint.X) - a.Radius > b.halfSize.X
            || Math.Abs(relativePoint.Y) - a.Radius > b.halfSize.Y
            || Math.Abs(relativePoint.Z) - a.Radius > b.halfSize.Z)
            return false;

        Vector3 closestPoint = Vector3.Zero;

        closestPoint.X = MathHelper.Clamp(relativePoint.X, -b.halfSize.X, b.halfSize.X);
        closestPoint.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(relativePoint.Y, -b.halfSize.Y, b.halfSize.Z);
        closestPoint.Z = MathHelper.Clamp(relativePoint.Z, -b.halfSize.Z, b.halfSize.Z);

        float distance = (closestPoint - relativePoint).LengthSquared();

        if (distance < a.Radius * a.Radius)
        {
            contact.contactPoint = Vector3.Transform(closestPoint, b.WorldTransform);
            contact.contactNormal = a.Position - contact.contactPoint;
            contact.contactNormal.Normalize();
            contact.penetrationDepth = a.Radius - (float)Math.Sqrt(distance);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: A cube has eight vertex, if all vertex are in the same side of the plane there is no collision

Comment: ok..i mean if my plane is vector3(0,-2,0) and my cube is vector3(0,5,0), its in the air and drop down..how do i collision test on the plane when the cube hits it?

Answer (score 0):

If either the plane or cube are not axis aligned -or- the cube (width,length,height) is not equivalent, you will find it easiest to test each corner position of the cube individually against the plane instead of the cube as a whole. Then when the first corner crosses the plane, register the collision.

But if both the plane and cube are axis aligned *AND* the cube is symmetrical (WLH), then think of the cube as a sphere whose radius is half the width of the cube.